# how to code the frequency of something that has been deleted by the user in a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am running with some issue. I will like to view the number of times a user has delete a value from a key even if the user exits the program, it will still retain that number. So that in future if the user will to delete any values again, it will use the existing number and add on from there.

edited: Just to add. All the dict will be store on a `.txt` file

```
dict= {}  #start off with an empty list

key_search = ("Enter to find a key")

if options_choose == 2:
    c = input('Which value would you like to change? ')
    c = change.lower()

    if change in list_of_value:
        loc = list_of_value.index(c)
        list_of_value.remove(c)
        correction = input("Enter correction: ")
        correction = correction.lower()
        print(f"value(s) found relating to the key '{key_search}' are:")
        list_of_value.insert(loc, correction)
        list_of_value = dict[key_search]

        for key, value in enumerate(list_of_value, 1):
            print(f"{key}.) {value}")
        else:
            print('Entry invalid')
```

Comment: Could you add a counter = 0 variable above the conditionals and then increment it whenever there is a change with counter+=1 in the second if loop?

Comment: To keep information even when the program exits, you have to write it to a persistent space - i.e. on your disk. So you have to write a file, fill a database, something like that.

Comment: Hi there! I have a suggest for you, instead of you use a `.txt` file prefer to use a `SQLite`, I think it sounds more interesting for you. So when the user delete a value from a key, you add a new occurrence in a column that refers a that specific key.

Comment: @RichardKYu Hi there! I have added the loop but I doubt it will update whenever I enter a new data in.

Comment: @Chinatown I would follow Tobias' advice about a storing the value into a database if you mean closing the program entirely, as in terminating it, since indeed the data will not exist once the program is closed. Perhaps, you can output it to a file and then read that file at the beginning of the program as a workaround. Check out with open() blocks.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the below screenshot I have exited and re-entered the program with the same counter.

[image]

You can adapt this to fit the features of your program. Since it seems like the code you provided is incomplete, I have substituted it with an example of dictionary modification to show how you can store and read a value after program termination.

You have to have a folder with test.py and modification.value.txt inside. Write "0" inside the text file.

```
ex_dict= {'example_entry':1}

#Read in the value stored into the text file.
with open('modification_value.txt','r') as file:
    counter = int(file.readline()) #counter value imported from file.

print('Counter: ', counter)

modify_dict = True #boolean to check when user wants to stop making changes


while modify_dict == True:

    for key in ex_dict:
        dict_key = key
    new_value = input('Enter value for new key.\n')
    ex_dict[dict_key] = new_value
    counter+=1

    print('New dictionary: ', ex_dict, '\n')

    response = input("Do you still want to modify Y/N?\n")
    if (response =='Y'):
        continue
    elif(response =='N'):
        modify_dict=False

#Write the value of the counter recorded by the program to the text file so the program can access it when it is run again after termination.
with open('modification_value.txt','w+') as file:
    file.write(str(counter))
```

Comment: Hi! I have tried your code, mixed it up a a little and it works! It is definitely insightful. Thank you.